# evt.target always returns the first input of the input list

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, attachment

I have a react file uploader which allows users to attach multiple file attachments. Whenever a user clicks on an input I read the `data-index` to check the position of the input.

```
renderFileUploader() {
        let file_attachment = this.state.file_attachment.map(function (b, i) {
            console.log("Checking the value of i in here");
            console.log(i);  /// Shows expected values (0..x)
      return (
                    <li key={i}>
                        <div className="attach-file-input">
                            <div className={b[3]}>
                                <label htmlFor="file_attachment"><i className={b[4]}></i></label>
                                <input type="file" name="file_attachment" data-index={i} data-type="file_attachment" id="file_attachment" onChange={this.upload.bind(this)} />
                                <p>{b[2]}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div><a href="#" onClick={this.updateList} data-type="file_attachment" data-index={i} data-delete="true" className="remove-icon">&times;</a></div>
                            <span className="uploaded-alert">{b[1]}</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
      )
    }.bind(this));

    return(
                <div className="form-group file-attachment-area">
                    <ul className="add-files">{file_attachment}</ul>
                    <a onClick={this.updateList} data-type="file_attachment" className="text-right add-attachment">&#43;</a>
                </div>
    );
  }
```

But when I upload a document and `upload` function is called at that time it always takes the index value as `0` and hence keeps on updating the element in the first position.

```
upload(evt, i) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(evt.target); // Console log to check position
    ....
}
```

On selecting any element my console log prints the following:

```
<input type="file" name="file_attachment" data-index="0" data-type="file_attachment" id="file_attachment">
```

So the data-index is always `0`

**EDIT: Corrected code**

```
<label htmlFor={"file_attachment" + [i]}><i className={b[4]}></i></label>
<input type="file" name="file_attachment" data-index={i} data-type="file_attachment" id={"file_attachment" + [i]} onChange={this.upload.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: shouldn't `data-index=0` not be `data-index="0"`?

Comment: One thing that might be causing a problem for you is that it appears that you are setting the `id` value of each element to the same value, and ID values must be unique.

Comment: @RichardMauritz sorry that was a typo; I edited the question to correct that

Comment: @KenH. you are right; that was the problem. I didn't realize that since I'm using a label for the input now so I have to provide unique id for each label; in my current situation it was using the same label every time and that's why my views weren't rendering properly

Comment: @KenH. can you add your comment as an answer; so I can accept it? That way if someone else has a similar problem they'll find your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that might be causing a problem for you is that it appears that you are setting the id value of each element to the same value, and ID values must be unique.

(You indicated that this was the solution, to change your ID values, so you can select this as the answer, @anonn023432.)